# When can we avoid using a constructor to initialize state?

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, constructor, ecmascript-6

In the example given on the *reactnativeexpress* website [here](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/component_api), `state = {count: 0}` is used in place of a constructor to initialize the count variable.

In the official Facebook docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html), they've said

> In general, you should initialize state in the constructor, and then call setState when you want to change it.

So I created a constructor to initialize `count` in the same manner:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {count: 0}
}
```

The code seems to work the same way (at least on the surface), so what's the difference between creating a constructor and initializing `count` as in the example?

Comment: The code on the website is not javascript (yet)

Comment: I don't understand. If it's ES6 isn't it the same? [ES6 vs JS](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306846/different-between-es6-and-javascript) Or is there something else I'm not getting

Comment: Its a proposal as Sag1v explains.

Comment: ES6 is a new version of javascript. the code on the website IS javascript, but just a proposal for a newer version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you attach as a [link](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/component_api) they use the [ES Class Fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields#es-class-fields--static-properties) which is a proposal (currently in stage 2).
That means you will need some extra presets / plugins of babel (or any other JavaScript compiler) to support it as it's not part of the official specifications of ECMAScript yet.

In the other example, you use the [class constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which is part of  ES2015.

Both will get you the same results, a property attached to the instance of the class.
which is basically just a syntactic sugar for the [prototype pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with ES6 Classes.

```
getFullName() {
  return this.props.firstName + this.props.lastName;
}
```

The above function will throw an error saying props is not defined.

```
getFullName = () => {
  return this.props.firstName + this.props.lastName;
}
```

The above code will pass the context of `this` into the function and will work good.

Similarly, your

```
state = {count: 0}
```

is executed in the context of the class [using appropriate `this` ].

The same `state` needs to be called using `this.state` within the constructor to bind it to appropriate context.